# signup as multiple user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

The use case of my application is I will have different kinds of user. They are:

- Agent
- Agency
- Manufacturer

They have their own kinds of attributes.

1 **User**

2 **Agent**

- ID
- FirstName
- MiddleName
- LastName
- DOB
- Sex
- Address:
  City
  Street
  Country
- Mobile Number
- Organization

3 **Agency**

- ID
- Name
- Address:
  City
  Street
  Country
- Contact Number (Multiple numbers can be added)
- Email
- VAT/PAN Number

4 **Manufacturer**

- ID
- Name
- Address:
  City
  Street
  Country
- Contact Number (Multiple numbers can be added)
- Email
- VAT/PAN Number

[ Note: Agency have agents. Manufacturer could be
associated with the agency or could have agents directly. ]

For this, I have designed my model in such a way

```
class Agency(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField()
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
    vat_number = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
agent/models.py

class Agent(models.Model):

    SEX_CHOICE = (
        ('male', 'Male'),
        ('female', 'Female'),
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agencies = models.ForeignKey(
        Agency,
        related_name="agents",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manufacturers = models.ForeignKey(
        Manufacturer,
        related_name="agents_manufacturer",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        blank=False,
        null=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        blank=False,
        null=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=SEX_CHOICE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField()
```

manufacturer/models.py:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="manufacturer")
    agency = models.ForeignKey(
        Agency,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="agency_manufacturer",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField()
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
    vat_number = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
```

I have used django-rest-auth for authentication. When i go to `/rest-auth/registration` the field like username, password1, password2 will be there. But i need which type of user, he/she is either. How do i handle such condition? Because, user should be able to login as either agent or agency or manufacturer. Can anyone help me at this, please?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against multiple user models. It is because, you introduce complexity to your logic wherever you need to do something with a user.

Moreover, you will get same IDs for different users and you will run into issues to deal with it.

I would recommend to create a custom User model and introduce something called a 'role' which would tell you what kind of user it is.

Then, you can add user profile to your model to add additional information based on the user's role.

Example of user model with a role attribute:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
     ROLE_CHOICES = (
         ('A', 'agent'),
         ('G', 'agency'),
         ('M', 'manufacturer'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

For the profile, you can add OneToOneField called user profile ( you can check django rest documentation how to do ).

To have different type of registration, you can start with the following view:

```
class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
   role = None
   def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(role=role)
```

And use it your urls for different type of roles like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^agents/', RegisterView.as_view(role='agent'), name="agent_register"),
    url(r'^agencies/', RegisterView.as_view(role='agency'), name="agency_register"),
    url(r'^manufacturers/', RegisterView.as_view(role='manufacturer'), name="manufacturer_register"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extend all your models from `django.auth.models.User`. or create your own user model and extend all your models from it.

when you want to detect type of user use code like this:

```
if Agent.objects.filter(pk=user.pk).exists():
     # its agent
if Agency.objects.filter(pk=user.pk).exists():
     # its agency
if Manufacturer.objects.filter(pk=user.pk).exists():
     # its manufacturer
```

to extend your models from user model just update your code same as below:

```
from django.auth.models import User

class Agent(User):
    <same as your example>


class Agency(User):
    <same as your example>


class Manufacturer(User):
    <same as your example>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Can you show me a bit of code for the "extending or create your own user model and extend all your models from it", please?

Comment: because i think i need the field for user to choose agent or agency or manufacturer while registering from rest-auth/registration endpoint as i am using django-rest-auth

Comment: OK you can create your own user model from this example: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser

Comment: so i should inherit the AbstractBaseUser and add the fields like `user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPE)` and
field like is_agent, is_agency and is_manufacturer so based on the user_type i update those field.

Comment: Yea. Thats the solution